# Spring Data 3 How to map single parameter with multiple values

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities

```
public class CarStatus {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    ...
}
public class Advertising {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private CarStatus carStatus;
    
    ...
}
```

and I have the following query

```
@Query("""
    from Advertising a
    where 1 = 1
    and (:carStatusIds is null or a.carStatus.id in (:carStatusIds))
""")
List<Advertising> queryTest(@Param("carStatusIds") Set<Long> carStatusIds);
```

Everything was working fine, but after I updated to spring boot 3 I see the following error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [[1, 2]] did not match expected type [BasicSqmPathSource(id : Long) ]
```

How do I need to map a parameter with multiple values switching to spring boot 3?